# Change Hydro1k with Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area to WGS 84

Tags: transform, raster, projection, r-raster

I am analyzing raster data using the projection of wgs84 and I also need Hydro1k data downloaded from USGS (https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/HYDRO1K). However Hydro1k use the projection of Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area with specific origins and other parameters. So I decided to transform the projection of Hydro1k to WGS 84 for future analysis. I tried one method found online, and the changed projection seems ok.

Below is the code I used and attributes of the raster:

```
#Import the selected raster after knowing name
As.fa.1k=raster(Path.all.1k[4])

#Show the attribute of the input raster from README file:
Projection used:  Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area

                  Units = meters

                  Pixel Size = 1000 meters

                  Radius of Sphere of Influence = 6,370,997 meters

                  Longitude of Origin = 20 00 00E

                  Latitude of Origin = 55 00 00N

                  False Easting = 0.0

                  False Northing = 0.0

#Custom the projection based on the origin of raster 
As.proj="+proj=laea +lon_0=100 +lat_0=45 +ellps=sphere"

#Assign CRS to layer
crs(As.fa.1k)=As.proj

#Get wgs4 projection
wgs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"

#Assign wgs84 to raster with lambert projection
As.wgs=projectRaster(As.fa.1k, crs=wgs)
```

However, the values in the raster whose projection wastransformed seems very weird:

```
#values in raster before being transformed
class       : RasterLayer 

dimensions  : 8384, 9102, 76311168  (nrow, ncol, ncell)

resolution  : 1000, 1000  (x, y)

extent      : -4462500, 4639500, -3999500, 4384500  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lon_0=-100 +lat_0=45 +ellps=sphere 

names       : na_fd 

values      : -9999, 255  (min, max)
```

-9999 should be the values of cells in the marine.

```
#values in raster after after transformed
class       : RasterLayer 

dimensions  : 1910, 5497, 10499270  (nrow, ncol, ncell)

resolution  : 0.0655, 0.04495  (x, y)

extent      : -180.0035, 180.05, -0.5929785, 85.26152  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 

names       : na_fd 

values      : 1, 55537  (min, max)
```

And I extract the values from the raster before being transformed, the maximum value is also 55537. It seems the values in raster before and after being transformed are very different.

How could I still keep the value of the raster before being transformed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

projectRaster will warp the raster cells during a reprojection, especially from a projected coordinate system (Lambert Azimuthal) to a geographic coordinate system (wgs84) and will require some interpolation of values.

Also you should notice the large difference in size of your cells, perhaps you could force the resolution with 'res=' in projectRaster?

Also, try 'method = "ngb"' as the interpolation method inside projectRaster to keep the values the same

Comment: Hi Sam.This is exactly what I want. Thanks very much. And also I noticed the background data of the input raster is 55537, means marine, which was replaced by NA. and "res=" and "method=" arg works very well. Thanks.